# whereClause syntax for Cost Distance parameter

Tags: arcpy, sql, spatial-analyst, cost-path

I am looking to create a sql expression regarding point feature class and selection based on 'Name' field to pass to arcpy.sa.CostDistance() param[0].

similat to:

```
savepath = env.workspace = r'G:\Xcel\Route Tool\Potter\Scratch.gdb'
weighted_Raster = r'G:\Xcel\Route Tool\Potter\Scratch.gdb\weighted_Raster'
fc = r'G:\Xcel\Route Tool\Potter\Data.gdb\Subs_w_dist'
Field = 'Name'
destValue = 'Coulter'
where_clause = createSQL(Field, destValue)


#Calculate the least accumulative cost distance for each cell to the nearest source over a cost surface.
outCostDist = arcpy.sa.CostDistance(where_clause, weighted_Raster,"", 'Output_Backlink')
outCostDist.save('distance_Raster')
```

How do I use make feature layer using variables as input. Similar to:

```
savepath = env.workspace = r'G:\Xcel\Route Tool\Potter\Scratch.gdb'
weighted_Raster = r'G:\Xcel\Route Tool\Potter\Scratch.gdb\weighted_Raster'
fc = r'G:\Xcel\Route Tool\Potter\Data.gdb\Subs_w_dist'
Field = 'Name'
destValue = 'Coulter'

destination = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc,'dest_Selection', [Field] = destValue)

#Calculate the least accumulative cost distance for each cell to the nearest source over a cost surface.
outCostDist = arcpy.sa.CostDistance(destination,weighted_Raster,"",'Output_Backlink')
outCostDist.save('distance_Raster')
distance_Raster = "distance_Raster"
```

Answer (score 1):

the input of cost distance should be a raster or a feature layer. You should create a feature layer using your feature class and your where clause, and use this layer as input in Cost distance. See the help on [makeFeatureLayer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000006p000000) here

in you example, the SQL statement should look like this (for shapefiles and file gdb) :

```
sql = '"' + fieldname + """" = '""" + value + "'"
```

or (personal gdb)

```
sql = "[" + fieldname + "] = '" + value + "'"
```

where fieldname and value are strings.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  But how do I make sql statement using variables as input? (See additional code above)